# jpa eclipselink modify field type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm making my first steps with JPA (eclipselink) developement, and i'm wondering if there's any good practice that may help reflecting changes brought to an entity into the data-base without re-creating the whole data-base.

In my case i have more than 30 entities, some of these are "correctly" defined and are already holding data rows on the data-base, but i've figured out that i made a mistake while defining some other entities by using the int type for the primary key instead of long, and the worst is that some of these entities are mapped by other entities, which means that they're used as foreign keys ... So i'm wondering if there's any "proper" way to deal with this without having to re-create the whole data-base. Re-creating  the data-base will force me to re-fill the rows of the already filled tables and waist much time.

Thanks in Advance
George

Comment: In other words - you want to change the primary key of an entity from 'int' to 'long' and remain consistent with the actual database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ints and longs are mapped to a number column in database. Changing the type in the entities won't change anything. You might have to change the precision of the columns in database so that the number is sufficiently large to accept any long value, but doing that is trivial in SQL, using an alter statement.

JPA is just a way to access the database. The database is not supposed to be created by the JPA engine. You may do that, but you're not forced to do that. You may do what you want with your database using SQL, and do whatever you want with your Java code. If they both map together when running the application, it will work.

Comment: changing the data-base with sql was my first reflection, but since the data-base gets automatically created based on the entities, i thought that modifying it automatically may be possible too, which is not if i correctly understand you... so i guess i'll use sql for that. thanks for the help

Comment: "The database is not supposed to be created by the JPA engine." - Yes it is, there's no reason to say that.

Comment: @Andrei: Have you ever been involved in an enterprise-level JPA project? Have you ever told a DBA that he had to use JPA to create the database? Do you delete your database and the gigabytes of data it contains and recreate it each time you have some changes in the design?

Comment: "Have you ever told a DBA that he had to use JPA to create the database?" - does this mean that using JPA to create data-base is not "recommanded" ? and if so why?

Comment: It's just not the right tool for the job. Using it to generate the SQL needed to create the tables, foreign keys, constraints and indexes might be acceptable, but to create the database itself, no. This is OK just for quick prototyping and tests. You'll need to set table spaces, user rights, etc. for a real database. And you'll often need, as you just noticed, to start from an older schema already containing data.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, I've actually been in that situation multiple times: the app on our demo servers had db schema autogen. by hib/jpa, on client machines the "DBA" refused this, refused even to manually use the hib. autgen. export. SQL. He did it himself "by hand" or whatever, was a big mess. This however does not mean that Hib/JPA are not good for this, it just means the "DBA" is bad. Check out devOps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps to see why such "DBA" is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your current schema automatically to reflect the modifications you've done inthe module by configuring EclipseLink like this:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
```

For major modifications to your model it does not guarantee proper update to the schema, but for smaller ones it should work ok.

Comment: This is what i did to create my tables, re-using it will not do any thing it will keep telling that tables already exist, unless i create some new entities. using "drop-and-create-tables" won't solve the problem neither because it will recreate everything and delete all the data i've inserted ...